# flink Windows, when do they start

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

I want to capture events from a Apache Flink [DataStream](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/), every "natural" hour. That is, I want to capture events in a window from 12:00:00 till 12:59:59, 13:00:00 till 13:59:59...

I have been using:

```
datastream.keyBy(0)
.timeWindow(Time.minutes(60))
```

But how do I know those 60 minutes start at every o'clock, and that the window is not, for instance, from 12:30:00 till 13:29:59?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer is [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html). To summarize:

For tumbling and sliding windows, windows are aligned with epoch (00:00:00 1 January 1970). Therefore, if you don't change the *offset* parameter, then your tumbling window will match the "o'clock" times.